# finding the largest set within a map

Tags: c++, set, maps

So I need help finding the last name with the most first names. I then need to print out the first names. I have gotten it to print out all of the names from every last name, but I can't figure out how to only print the one with most first name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

typedef set <string> fnset;

main()
{
  map <string, fnset *> lnames;
  map <string, fnset *>::iterator lnit;
  fnset *fnames;
  fnset::iterator fnit;
  string fn, ln;

  while (cin >> fn >> ln) {
    lnit = lnames.find(ln);
    if (lnit == lnames.end()) {
       fnames = new fnset;
       lnames.insert(make_pair(ln, fnames));
    } else {
      fnames = lnit->second;
    }
    fnames->insert(fn);
   }

   for (lnit = lnames.begin(); lnit != lnames.end(); lnit++) {    
    fnames = lnit->second;
    for (fnit = fnames->begin(); fnit != fnames->end(); fnit++) {
        cout << *fnit << endl;
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like you're making this too complicated. Why are the values in the map _pointers_ to a set of strings via a typedef? A simple `map<string, set<string>>` will suffice. At the end you don't need a nested loop, but just a single loop to find which key in the map corresponds to the value with the most entries in the set, followed by a second loop printing out the contents of the set.

Comment: So you have a map of last names and first names (last name is the key), and you're looking to find the last name which has the most amount of first names? Note that valid C++ only defines a `main()` which returns an `int`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `std::max_element` from `<algorithm>` library. One of its overload has the following form.

```
 ForwardIt max_element( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp );
```

`first` and `last` and iterators to the container, and `comp` is the comparision function object used to compare two elements. For more info, check cppreference page, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element.

```
#include <algorithm>

auto largest = std::max_element(
    lnames.begin(), lnames.end(), [](auto const& p1, auto const& p2) {
        return p1.second->size() < p2.second->size();
    });

for (auto const& name : *largest->second)
    std::cout << name << '\t';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest using a [`multimap<string, string> lnames`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) here. You could populate it like this:

```
for(string fn, ln; cin >> fn >> ln;) {
    lnames.insert(make_pair(ln, fn));
}
```

Then just use iterators with [`multimap::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/upper_bound) to find the largest:

```
auto max_start = cbegin(lnames);
auto max_end = cbegin(lnames);
size_t max_distance = 0U;

for(auto it_start = cbegin(lnames), it_finish = cbegin(lnames); it_start != cend(lnames); it_start = it_finish) {
    it_finish = lnames.upper_bound(it_finish->first);

    auto it_distance = distance(it_start, it_finish);

    if(it_distance > max_distance) {
        max_distance = it_distance;
        max_start = it_start;
        max_finish = it_finish;
    }
}
```

And finally to output this simply use [`ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator)s:

```
copy(max_start, max_finish, ostream_iterator<string>(cout, " "))
```